# Display keyboard above a UITabBar

Tags: swift, uitabbar

In one of my `UIViewController`'s I would like to have the keyboard display above my `UITabBar`. Currently it opens up on top of my `UITabBar` so you have to get rid of it first before you can navigate by tapping on an icon in my `UITabBar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware I don't think the keyboard can be repositioned. The docs for the keyboard and what you can do to it can be found here: [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: I couldn't find it... then probably the next best thing is making my own numeric keypad... it is just 10 buttons. Thanks, Mark.